# What is meant by the (apparent) diminuitive "cani?"

Tags: modismos

There's "Espana Cani," and Ana Cani, the Mexican-American singer on the Lawrence Welk show.

Google translate gives me "gypsy."

Somehow, that seems too literal, because it seems like a "diminuitive." But it might refer to a dark skinned person.

Is it a diminuitive, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cani`, as it is, sounds to me as a diminutive of `canijo`, but is also a urban tribe (refers to people from the suburbs, violent and without much education. Is more or less what some people address by ["white trash"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cani)).

`Cañí`, with the '**ñ**' is indeed an adjetive, that means both "gypsy" and "typical or folklorical"

> La España **cañí** is a set phrase that refers to folkloric Spain and is sometimes used derogatorily. It must be distinguished from **cani**, a violent urban tribe of Spain.
>
> <sub>[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%B1%C3%AD)</sub>

So, `cañí` can used refer to gypsies, but I have never heard it to actually call somebody "gypsy" if they are not (Also, probably we favor `gitano` to designate the race, although could be be referred as [`calé`](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=cal%C3%A9) as well. They call the non-gypsy people [`payos`](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=payos)).

Comment: In spite of what Wikipedia says, I would never consider canis as violent. Loutish, OK, but not really violent. *Cani* can be quite accurately translated to English as *chav*.

Comment: @Gorpik to British English, at least. I'm not sure a good American translation. Absolutely agree that *cani* doesn't really imply violence

Comment: @guifa Sure, *chav* us only British English. *White trash* may indeed be an American version, but their behaviour is quite different. *Chavs*, on the other side, are almost exactly the same, as far as I know.

Comment: @Gorpik, I think that when they are described as "violent" is more like "verbally aggressive" than prone to get into a fist fight. See how they are portrayed in that entry to the Urban Dictionary, addressing each other with a rather harsh language (were they are described as _chavs_, BTW). Although I don't consider them "white trash" the word has some pejorative connotations in Spanish, and I could not find anything better to convey it in English.

Comment: @Diego *White trash* is also the best American equivalent I can find. The social group is more or less the same, though their general behaviour is not. As for the origin of the word *cani*, it can very well be what you propose. Apart from this meaning, *Cani* is a more or less common nickname usually applied to short or youngish people.